# shorthand for workbook().worksheets()?

Tags: vba, excel

I may be blind, but I've been working with VBA for a few years now but still write out

```
Workbook("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

or (after dimming Book1 as a workbook and Sheet1 as a string

```
Book1.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A1").Value
```

Is there a way that you can shorthand the "workbook.sheets" part (without doing a "With" statement)?

Comment: You should probably avoid `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` as it returns an `Object`, which means all of your subsequent calls will be late bound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.  Just do it the right way:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Book1")
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim x As Variant
x = ws.Range("A1").Value
```

(Sorry Mat's Mug - I had to have a bit of a dig with that first line :D)

Comment: Hahaha golden...so, *use short disemvoweled identifier names* huh? ;-)

Comment: You beat me to it by about 30 seconds :)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - short, but don't care whether they are disemvoweled - I'm lazy and hate typing more characters than I need to.

Comment: @DanDonoghue - I had to post an answer once I saw Mat's Mug's answer :D

Comment: Unicorns are overrated anyway :)

Comment: Eh, I meant my answer as some 2nd-degree thing.. I hope people will get it ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - It will be concerning if your answer becomes the accepted one! :D

Comment: Ah, nothing matters anymore - all I needed was +2 to get to 20,000 points! =)

Comment: Well look at that, that other 10K went pretty fast! congrats!

Answer (score 9):

Sure. Just do it the wrong way:

```
Sheet1.Activate
Range("A1").Value = 42
```

Unqualified in a standard code module, `Range` is a member of `_Global`, which implements its `Range` property by returning the specified range on whichever worksheet happens to be active... if any (in a worksheet's code-behind, it implicitly refers to `Me.Range`, i.e. a range on *that sheet*).

If you're going to implicitly work off `ActiveSheet`, you can also defer type resolution to run-time with a less performant *late-bound call*, and make the host application (here Excel) *evaluate* a *bracketed expression* for even faster typing:

```
[A1].Value = 42
```

Heck, the `Range` type has a *default member* that points to its `Value`, so you could even do this:

```
[A1] = 42
```

As you can see, *less* code isn't always *better* code. Qualify your `Worksheet` member calls, and use default members consciously and judiciously.

Every time someone makes an implicit call on `_Global`, a baby unicorn dies and two new Stack Overflow questions involving errors stemming from unqualified worksheet calls are summonned from the darkness.

---

Sarcasm aside, if you find yourself constantly chaining such `Workbook("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(...)...` calls, then you're constantly dereferencing the same objects, over and over: that's not only redundant to type, it's also redundant to execute.

If you're working with `ThisWorkbook` (the workbook running the code), you **never** have a legitimate reason to do this to dereference a worksheet that exists at compile-time. Use its *code name* instead:

```
Sheet1.Range(...)...
```

If the workbook only exists at run-time, or otherwise isn't `ThisWorkbook`, then at one point in time your code opened or created that workbook - there's no need to ever dereference it from the `Workbooks` collection, ...if you stored the reference in the first place:

```
Set wbExisting = Workbooks.Open(path)
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
```

Same for worksheets that are created at run-time in other workbooks by your code: keep that object reference!

```
Set wsNew = wbNew.Worksheets.Add
```

This leaves only 1 scenario where you would ever need a string to dereference a specific worksheet: the sheet already exists in a workbook that isn't `ThisWorkbook`.

If that workbook's structure isn't (or can't be) protected, avoid hard-coding the sheet's index or name if you can:

```
Set wsExisting = wbExisting.Worksheets(1) ' user may have moved it!
Set wsExisting = wbExisting.Worksheets("Summary") ' user may have renamed it!
```

---

#### TL;DR

Work with objects. Declare objects, assign object references, and work with them, pass them as arguments to your procedures. There's no reason to be constantly dereferencing objects like you're doing. *If* you need to do it, then you only ever need to do it *once*.

Comment: +1 for making it clear that the answer is posted sarcastically, and explaining why the lack of proper qualification leads to so many questions.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'm going to take the "Book1" name literally, and assume that you're writing code to deal with a *new* workbook - probably with something like:

```
Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
Workbooks.Add
Set myWorkbook = Workbooks("Book1")
```

That's already a bad start, because:

1. The language of the user will determine the "Book" part of the name.
2. The numeric suffix will increment with every additional new workbook

So, many inexperienced coders try this:

```
Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
Workbooks.Add
Set myWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
```

But that's open to error too. What if there are event handlers looking to change the active workbook? What is the user changes the active workbook while stepping through code?

The best way to assign your myWorkbook variable is with something like this:

```
Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
Set myWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
```

And, just like when adding a new workbook, you should follow the same approach when opening an existing workbook:

```
Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
Set myWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Foo.xlsx")
```

In both cases, you *know* you've got a reference to the correct workbook, and **you don't care what it is called *or* whether it is active**. You've just made your code more robust *and* more efficient.

Alternatively, if your VBA is working with the workbook in which it resides, you can just use `ThisWorkbook` or the codename of the sheet(s).

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Name

'By default, a sheet named "Sheet" has a codename of 'Sheet1'
Debug.Assert Sheet1.Name = ThisWorkbook("Sheet1").Name

'But give meaningful names to your sheet name and 
'sheet codename, and your code becomes clearer:
Debug.Assert AppSettings.Name = ThisWorkbook("Settings").Name
```

You'll probably find that most of your code deals with the workbook in which it resides, or existing workbooks that your code opens, or new workbooks that your code creates. All of those situations are handled above. On the rare occasions in which your code must interact with workbooks that are already open, or are opened by some other process, you'll need to refer to the workbook by name, or enumerate the Workbooks collection:

```
Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
Set myWorkbook = Workbooks("DailyChecklist.xlsx")

For Each myWorkbook In Workbooks
  Debug.Print myWorkbook.Name
Next myWorkbook
```

The one exception being add-ins, which can't be enumerated using the `Workbooks` collection, but can be referenced with `Workbooks("MyAddin.xlam")`

Comment: "'By default, a sheet named "Sheet" has a codename of 'Sheet1' " - that's not true - Worksheets(1) at the time the VBE is first opened in the workbook is given the codename `Sheet1` so, if you create a workbook, insert a new sheet while on "Sheet1" (the new sheet will be named "Sheet4" by default if you have three worksheets created in each new workbook), then open the VBE, you will find "Sheet4" has codename `Sheet1`, "Sheet1" will have codename `Sheet2`, "Sheet2" will have codename `Sheet3` and "Sheet3" will have codename `Sheet4`.

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
Sub temp()
    Dim WB As Workbook, WS As Worksheet
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set WS = WB.Sheets(2)
    MsgBox WS.Range("A2").Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the worksheet variable along with its parent workbook

```
Dim wb1s1 As Worksheet
Set wb1s1 = Workbook("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1")
```

And then write

```
wb1s1.Range("A1").Value
```